UB status of initializing a reference to last+1 array element?
The following code compiles in GCC, CLANG, and MSVC. It initializes the int ir to refer to the non-existent a[1] which is one beyond the end of a.
consteval int foo()
{
    int a[1]{ 42 };
    int& ir = a[1];
    return *(&ir-1);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int ci=foo();
    return ci;
}

This compiles in spite of the core constant expression evaluation seeming to contain UB. See this which contains "A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function."
A more recent n4950 draft removes this language.
Is this no longer UB?

First of all, C++ doesn't have any kind of bounds-checking. It's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure you don't go out of bounds. With that said, it is allowed to have pointers to one-beyond the end of an array. That's really how iterators work, and &ir can be seen as the end iterator for the array a.

@Someprogrammerdude Sure. And if I try to initialize the reference with a[2] it will fail to compile since core constant evaluations are generally checked for UB. Seems a[2] is treated similarly to a pointer. I can initialize a pointer to a then increment it once. Compiles fine. But if I increment it again - compile failure. Outside of a core constant expression evaluation, it happily compiles all that UB. But is the above code no longer UB given the new language in N4950?

Note that int& ir = *(a+20); return *(&ir-20); compiles and works as expected... but it certainly is UB in the current version of C++. Once compiled, a reference is just a pointer and you can even get references set to nullptr (which is UB, but it's easy to do it).

@AlexisWilke Doesn't compile with CLANG or MSVC. Compiles with GCC. GCC should also not compile but is quite tolerant even allowing reinterpret cast in evaluating core constant expressions when it should not. They are prohibited in CCEs

CWG453 made the change to the working draft that you observed. It is closely related to CWG2823, which was approved a few months before CWG453, and addressed the issue of whether it's UB to dereference a null pointer or a past-the-end pointer.
CWG2823 is what makes it clear that your code is invalid. The expression a[1] is equivalent to *(a + 1), and a + 1 is a past-the-end pointer. Because a + 1 does not point to an object, applying the * operator to it violates [expr.unary.op]/1 (as amended by CWG2823). This is UB at runtime, and a diagnosable error at compile time (but as you say, compilers haven't yet caught up). We never actually reach the question of whether or not the reference binding is valid.
CWG453 was concerned about what it means for an object to be "valid" for the purposes of reference binding; this was never clear in the previous wording. Note that once CWG2823 was resolved, it was no longer necessary to ask the question of whether a reference is allowed to bind to a "null glvalue" or a "past-the-end glvalue" because it would always be invalid to produce such a glvalue in the first place. The only remaining issue was to address the case where (e.g. due to reinterpret_cast shenanigans) a program attempts to bind a reference to an object of the wrong type. This was made UB in most cases and the unclear "valid object or function" text was removed.

Interesting. I'm reading these. Thanks for the links!  BTW, if the pointer is even transiently increased beyond the last+1, the MSVC compiler flags UB. For example changing the returns statement from return *(&ir -1); to return *(&ir +1 - 2); causes the compiler to flag UB. Might also be related to the fact that one can initialize a reference with an uninitialized lvalue w/o UB. But using its value  w/o initializing is UB.

Yep. Looks like it's UB. Thanks.
